# Focus to Debug Console window when running tests in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode brings into focus the **Test Results** window when running tests, and **Debug Console** when launching the debugger. This - of course, is logical and expected, but is there some config to override that behavior and bring into focus **Debug Console** when running tests? My tests print to std out, which Test Results does not display. I see no suitable options under `"debug.console.*"` for doing this.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking in the wrong place; the config was under `"testing.*"`,

```
"testing.openTesting": "neverOpen"
```